# mod_rewrite or mod_alias?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf, mod-alias

I have a server, its httpd.conf already has some "*RedirectMatch permanent*" directives in it.

I'm not that familiar with mod_alias, I've only ever used mod_rewrite.

What's the basic difference?  I don't see a "L" flag in mod_alias to stop processing rules.

Which one should I use for best practices of redirecting from one sub-domain to another?

Can I use both at the same time and will it be obvious which takes precedence?

Comment: I have found out in the end that mod_rewrite is more powerful and is a superset of mod_alias.

I was able to successfully use both mod_alias and mod_rewrite rules in the same httpd.conf file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

mod_alias is basically a simpler version of mod_rewrite. It can't do some things that mod_rewrite can, such as manipulate the query string. If you're able to choose either of them, I don't see any reason that you'd want to use mod_alias.

Is there a specific reason you need to try to use both together?

[Apache mod_rewrite & mod_alias tricks you should know](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20131107001958/http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/2007/09/12/apache-mod-rewrite) seems to be a good article about the two. It notes at one point that mod_rewrite rules get executed before mod_alias ones.

Comment: The only reason I want to use both together, is that there are about 30 existing rules using mod_alias.  I've written my own mod_rewrite rules that I'd like to add, and I'd rather not have to recreate the existing rules in mod_rewrite.

Comment: "mod_rewrite rules get executed before mod_alias ones." - Wish that gem was in the apache documentation. In my setup using both rewrite and alias; that's exactly what I'm now observing.

Comment: Official documentation: “**mod_rewrite should be considered a last resort**, when other alternatives are found wanting. Using it when there are simpler alternatives leads to configurations which are confusing, fragile, and hard to maintain.” [_When not to use mod_rewrite_](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html). – Using the most powerful system simplifies decisionmaking but is often not the best approach to good maintainability. There are good reasons to skip mod_rewrite for mod_alias. mod_alias should be the primary choice.

Answer (score 4):

As the accepted answer says: `mod_rewrite` can do things which `mod_alias` can't. However the main benefit of `mod_alias` is that it is easier to use.

The apache docs say that we should use `mod_alias` for simple things like redirects and `mod_rewrite` only for things we cannot do with simpler modules like `mod_alias`. View the docs: [When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html).