# Redirect site with .htaccess but exclude one folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to 301 redirect an entire website, but exclude everything in a folder called `/uploads` which exists in the `/root` directory.

I have googled for this, but didn't come up with anything, or I didn't think what I saw was right.

Can we crack this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^uploads($|/) http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This rule does match any URL path that does *not* begin with either `/uploads` or `/uploads/` (leading `/` is missing in the pattern due to the path prefix removal when used in .htaccess files) and redirects the request to the corresponding path at *example.com*.

Comment: Is there an option to do this in background, so the user doesn't get actually redirected, but all the request gets proxied into another address?

Comment: @burninggramma Try `P` instead of `R=301`.

Comment: @Gumbo I get a 403 forbidden

Comment: Thank you. I used your answer for my own convoluted requirements http://stackoverflow.com/a/35435802/80353

Answer (score 73):

Simple answer I just stumbled upon myself.

At the top before any other calls add the following

```
RewriteRule ^(uploads) - [L]
```

Comment: If anyone is curious what the [L] does: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. I had used `Redirect` from mod_alias, and this doesn't seem to work together. So please add some info how this plays together with redirecting all other pages to *another* domain, as many others tell me that mod_alias is not the right choice for doing domain redirection.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann mod_alias and mod_rewrite do not play well together. I am not going to go into details as to why (because it is outside the scope of this question) but here is a link to another question that may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/808089/588005

Comment: This say uri that  starts with "uploads"  shouldn't be changed, and as no redirection is implicitly set, it can cause redirection loop.
Why do you use braces here?

Comment: this breaks redirection of "uploads_b"

Answer (score 42):

I think you want this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you get `500 Internal Error` then double-check that you have a space between **}** and **!** on the second line.

Comment: How i wrote my condition was 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app|app/.*)$` in order to get this to work. /app/ obviously being the folder i wanted to skip redirecting.

Answer (score 12):

A mod-alias based solution

**Redirect all except a specific folder**

Add the following line to your root/.htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!uploads).*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1
```

This will redirect all pages  (excluding /uploads/*) from your old domain to the newdomain.

Comment: This works perfectly! Very useful, since I couldn't use mod_rewrite because was not enabled on a customer's server

Comment: Here is my solution for a virtual `http` host whose only purpose is to contain the `.well-known` directory for `certbot certonly --webroot` (let's encrypt): `RedirectMatch permanent ^/((?!\.well-known)(/.*)?)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1`

Comment: It's good to have this solution for cases where the RewriteEngine is not used; in (virtual) hosts which use RewriteRules as well, it is better to use the `RewriteCond` solution.