# .htaccess - redirecting several pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been trying to wrap my head around .htaccess for most of the weekend, but I keep stumbling; I can get the server to work with one set of rules, but no more than one at a time.

My application is made up of several pages:

- The Homepage pulls in content from the Detail page, (as well as content that the Detail page doesn't include), with an optional query string argument; e.g. `?s=item-name`
- The Detail page pulls in content with an optional query string argument (the same argument as the homepage; e.g. `?s=item-name` - this would refer to exactly the same content)
- A Collection page
- A Related page

Each of these pages is a php file in the document root (index.php, detail.php, collection.php, related php).

What I would like to achieve:

- The user should be able to go to `mydomain.com/detail/` or `mydomain.com/detail` (so allow trailing slashes) instead of `mydomain.com/details.php`
- If present, the query string argument (`?s=item-name`) should be entered after the page's trailing slash (so `mydomain.com/item-name` instead of `mydomain.com/?s=item-name`; `mydomain.com/detail/item-name` instead of `mydomain.com/detail.php?s=item-name`. This would be the case for all pages, so setting the rule on one page at a time seems rather cumbersome...

This is what my .htaccess file looks like at present, after much fiddling:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This allows the homepage to pull in the correct content, and I'm sure it's not too far off allowing *any* page to do the same, but I can't quite fathom it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Specifics
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.+)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %1.php?s=%2 [L]

# EDIT 1: This will also check for root pages. See notes below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L,QSA]

# Everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

**Explanation:**

1. First, we check that the full `REQUEST_FILENAME` does not exist.
2. Then, we check to see that the format is as follows: `/<something-without-slash>/<everything else>` (with an optional trailing slash).
3. We then check to see if our first condition-capture exists as a PHP file in the document root. For example, if we request `foo/bar`, it would check to see if `/foo.php` exists.
4. Then we simply route the request to the correct file, with the correct query string.

So, in your case, when you request `detail/item-name`, the server would actually be looking at `detail.php?s=item-name` to provide you with a response.

**Note:** If it does not exist, the request will simply send the request to `index.php`.

**Edit:** Have added detection for root pages. Note, however, that I cannot get it to leave a slash for this kind of detection as it automatically amends `.php` to the empty `s` query paramater. Not sure why...
This is why when it reaches this stage, it will remove any trailing slashes. This is also good for SEO ratings/rankings as it is seen as one page, and not two duplicates.

Comment: very nearly there, I think - but at the moment requests to detail.php (`mydomain.com/detail`) are being interpreted as index.php/?s=detail.

Comment: Missed that, sorry. Give me a sec.

Comment: Sooooooo very close... but it's nerfing calls to js and css files... -_-

Comment: It might be to do with how I'm referencing them in the page head... `href="/_includes/css/main.css"`?

Comment: I see - just tested it on my side, and you're right - it does mess it up. I'll figure it out quick.

Comment: Fixed on my end. Just added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` at the top of my original edit.

Comment: I do believe that's done it. Thanks! This has been bugging me for days.

Comment: Argh! It's redirecting my /manage/ folder..... (for the cms)... what command should I use to stop redirects if the folder exists?

Comment: Ah, found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder