# How can I run Wordpress and phpBB in the same Apache server?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, alias, phpbb3

I've been testing my new web site in a `MAMP` environment.

The folder `/wordpress/` contains a `Wordpress` web site.

The folder `/bb/` contains a `phpBB3` forum.

When I complete them, I'll have to move those sites to my server machine running with Mac OS X Server 10.9. It is basically an Apache server.

I thought that with `[Apache Alias][1]` functionality I could trick the URLs. For example, a request for `www.xxx.com` will be taken to `www.xxx.com/wordpress/`. This way visitors don't have to bother typing `wordpress`.

On the other hand, a request for the forum should be treated in a separate way. For instance, `www.xxx.com/bb/` should be treated as `http://www.mbs.med.kyoto-u.ac.jp/bb/` itself.

To achieve the above, I run preliminary tests on Apatche Alias. But it seems that my strategy may not work. I thought the following would work.

```
Alias / /wordpress
Alias /bb /bb
```

Currently, only the phpBB3 forum has been transferred to the server. So I made a dummy `wordpress` folder containing an html file to test the behaviour of Alias. `Alias / /wordpress` can show the html file in the dummy `/wordpress/` folder in a browser.

However, `Alias /bb /bb` didn't work well. `www.xxx.com/bb` showed an index page for the content of `bb` folder (i.e. list of file names), rather than showing the phpBB3 forum running. The results suggest that the Alias can be useful for simple html pages, but php-driven web pages may have serious problems.

Is there a way to achieve what I planned? Or is it just not possible? Could it be phpBB3 or Wordpress configurations related to URL? Or do I have to redesign the whole thing with [WP-united](http://www.wp-united.com/), [WP phpBB Bridge](http://www.e-xtnd.it/wp-phpbb-bridge/) or something (for our purpose, the Wordpress site and the phpBB3 forum don't need to be integrated)? Your expert advices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a .htaccess file in your root folder. Then something like this should work (didn't test it)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bb/
RewriteRule (.*) /wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Source: [Redirect site with .htaccess but exclude one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder))

Comment: Cheers! I would never reach this by myself. I'll study and try it.