# How to redirect website by htaccess HTTP_HOST

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem with my website. I have a domain abc-xyz.com and I was uploaded source into a directory like name /folder . Ok, I can visit website by abc-xyz.com/folder . But problem detected. I need rewrite URL! Because root directory running another website, i want to rewrite URL for childrent directory /folder . And "http://abc-xyz.com/folde/r" is a string.
So i was try:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abc-xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc-xyz.com/test/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it not workly. when i visit http://abc-xyz.com/test/folder/ . It direct to abc-xyz.com (and it's a another website).

Thanks for read, and please help me. Sorry because my English very bad :(

Comment: Yes. when you visit http://examp.com/folder/index.php/?act=dosomething&u=12 I need it rewrite examp.com/folder/dosomething/12 . Same it!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to redirect all requests into a subdirectory of a site?

e.g.

http://abc-xyz.com/something.txt goes to http://abc-xyz.com/folder/something.txt

http://abc-xyz.com/directory/file.txt goes to http://abc-xyz.com/folder/directory/file.txt ?

Does the solution from this page work for you (which I've edited slightly below)?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3414030/3944304

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^folder($|/) http://abc-xyz.com/folder/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have 2 site separate. I want to rewrite URL for a website in a subfolder. And file .htaccess only rewrite in it,

Exam: exam.com/test/index.php/?something=abc&uid=11 --> exam.com/test/something/abc/11 <== it good (.htaccess at subfolder). When i visit exam.com/index.php/?nothing=xyz&uid=1 --> exam.com/nothing/xyz/1 <== i written it ok. But i  don't know write for subfolder :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite think I follow. You might want to untick my post, so that others will come looking as well.

Comment: don't worry. I very thankful for the help of you. Have a nice day to you