# Redirect site with .htaccess but exclude two+ folders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3414030/3817111), you can exclude a single subfolder from a redirect like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^uploads($|/) http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

How would I expand that to include two or more separate subfolders?

Answer (score 5):

You can exclude multiple folders with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-folder/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all requests that don't start with the folder /test/ or /my-folder/ to newdomain.com.

*Source: based on broken code from [here](https://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/redirect-entire-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-or-more-directories/).*

Comment: While this works, I wonder if it's possible to do it in one line

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to read and maintain if you follow [a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144956/1824988) to the question you referenced.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Do not rewrite these directories
RewriteRule ^(uploads) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(second) - [L]

# Rewrite all other URL
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming to redirect a Wordpress site using these rules, it is essential that "index.php" is included in the list of exclusions, otherwise the exclusions won't work - because Wordpress processes everything through index.php.

Here is an example of what it will look like with Wordpress, if you want to redirect a domain, except you still want admins to be able to login to the previous wp-admin section. And as an extra example sitemap_index.xml is excluded from the redirects too.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin($|/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap_index.xml$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```