# Redirect site with .htaccess but exclude one folder while repointing index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain that contains a shop installed in the root and WordPress in a subfolder called /web/

```
/public_html/ # shop
            /web/ # wordpress
```

I am in the process of moving the shop to a new domain. WordPress is remaining put.

I wish to 301 redirect all shop pages but exclude WordPress requests. This part works.

```
# Redirect shop to new domain
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^web($|/)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The following similar threads lead me to the above solution.

- [Redirect site with .htaccess but exclude one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder)
- [Redirect site with .htaccess but exclude two+ folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758441/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-two-folders)

What I want to do now is make it so that visitors coming in to the old domain are simply redirected to /web/. I've tried adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
```

but this is not working to exclude the root index file.

I think I need another RewriteRule in there somewhere.

Comment: Replaced the !^/index\.php$ with RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ to stop the index redirecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more trial and error I have come to the following result that is working for me.

```
# Redirect shop to new domain
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^web($|/)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect root to /web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.current-domain.co.uk/web/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I edited the first RewriteRule and excluded the root "/"

I then created a second RewriteRule moving only the root to "/web/"