# How to redirect all pages to another domain except for two subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess

How do I 301 redirect all pages to another domain except for two sub-directories?

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder).

Comment: Please provide your current rules or try something on your own and put it here.

Comment: `RewriteRule !^(?:dir1|dir2)($|/) http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE,NE]` should work

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @anubhava. Add an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^(?:dir1|dir2)($|/) http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

`!^(?:dir1|dir2)` is negation match that excludes `dir1` and `dir2` from this redirection.