# htaccess redirect with condition

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect some page in website :

site.com/sub1/sub2/sub3 redirect to site.com/newsub I write this code for this redirect

```
RedirectMatch 301 /sub1/sub2/sub3/(.*) /newsub//$1
```

everything is ok but I need this url not redirected

site.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/pages

how can I do this?

Comment: Did you already try [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder) ?

Comment: I try to RedirectMatch 301 !^page($|/) /sub1/sub2/sub3/(.*) /newsub//$1 but get error 500 on my page

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have 'site.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/pages' in a variable? if yes, then

```
RedirectMatch 301 (/sub1/sub2/sub3/)(.*) /newsub//old_url=$1$&$2
```

gives you '/sub1/sub2/sub3/pages' in old_url and you just add domain name