# Simple rewritecond in htaccess doesn't work as expected

Tags: .htaccess

This is super simple but it's driving me crazy! I have a website at http://example.org/ and a subdirectory at http://example.org/ccc/

I want to redirect anything **outside of** the /ccc/ directory to a different website.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ccc/?.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-website.com/$1 [L]
```

But this code doesn't work, it redirects the /ccc/ directory. According to my research and testing with [this htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), it should not redirect because the RewriteCond is checking against /ccc with optional slash and other characters after it.

What is happening? Does this look correct?

Edit: This method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144956/470480) is also not working, the CCC domain is being redirected:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ccc index.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://new-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

PHP 5.4.45, Apache/2.2.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ccc/` directory doesn't have a separate .htaccess, you may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/ccc[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new-website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. An example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: I've never seen THE_REQUEST, that explains a lot of the weird behavior I was running in to! It never occurred to me that the REQUEST_URI changed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [L] isn't behaving normally and I'm guessing it's the old version of Apache (2.2.31) because these rules worked on a separate website. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850831/470480) which seemed to work for this case, the third line below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ccc/? index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} != 200
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-website.com/$1 [L]
```

Explanation from that question:

> The problem is that once the [L] flag is processed, all the next RewriteRules are indeed ignored, however, the file gets processed AGAIN from the begin, now with the new url.
>
> This magic Condition will not process the catch all if the file was already redirected.

Comment: But this will not work for a file inside `/ccc/` directory e.g. `http://example.org/ccc/somefile`