# htaccess - redirect everything to index.php except a folder and specific files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been fighting with this for way too long.  I have a my PHP site hosted with a .htaccess file for rewriting and redirecting.  It has been working great so far.  Now I simply want to add a subfolder, `/pp` that everything inside it does not get redirected or rewritten, basically it should not get touched by my .htaccess stuff.

Now when I go to mysite.com/pp/test.php (that file does exist), it redirects to mysite.com/index

Here is what I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine On

#remove www for all traffic
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#prevent redirect of submit
RewriteRule ^/?submit$ submit.php [L]

#prevent redirect of paypal
RewriteRule ^/?admin$ admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?testPPButton$ testPPButton.php [L]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pp/.* [NC]  // this line is not working for some reason
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Options -Indexes
```

Updated .htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On

# skip /pp/* from all rules below
RewriteRule ^pp(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]

#remove www for all traffic
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#prevent redirect of submit
RewriteRule ^/?submit$ submit.php [L]

#prevent redirect of paypal
RewriteRule ^/?admin$ admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?testPPButton$ testPPButton.php [L]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Refer to this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder)

Comment: I actually saw that link in my search.  Adding `!^pp($|/)` after either of my `RewriteRule` commands produces an internal server error.

Comment: try changing the permissions of the folder causing the internal server error

Answer (score 0):

Just below `RewriteEngine On` line add this to skip `pp/` and everything under this folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip /pp/* from all rules below
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\s/+pp[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,NC]

# rest of your rules go below this
```

Comment: Tried it, still redirecting me to /index

Comment: I thought you are trying to skip pp folder from rewrite. What is url you're using to test and what is exact error happening?

Comment: I'm typing example.com/pp/test.php and it's sending me to example.com/index

Comment: That is correct, I don't want files in that folder rewritten or redirected.

Comment: Is there a htacceas inside pp folder? Can you show latest htacceas with my suggested rule in question?

Comment: If you're seeing URL changing in browser then test from a new browser or curl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188246/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-anubhava).