# How to set when open certain urls it is not processed by wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

i have 2 system in one hosting

1. i build using wordpress for landing page
2. the system i build using codeigneter

the problem is in the codeigniter system, i have a example (transactions page), if i access the transactions page error like this :

DataTables warning: table id=transactions - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

i check the error in inspect element (i'm using google chrome) : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" i try to open the url redirect to wordpress.

my question is :

1. how to prevent/disable wordpress can not access or process the url?

this my htaccess on wordpress :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to edit your `.htaccess` and have it ignore a folder. Plenty of resources on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder

Comment: thanks for reply sir, which one should I change .htaccess on wordpress or codeignter sir? thanks before

Comment: I'd probably do a bit of research on how `.htaccess` files work, before you dive in any further.

Comment: thanks sir for reply, any resource sir? i try resource from you not work, still erorr. thanks before