# Redirect any page and folder to the homepage of the new site

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a domain with four websites to close shortly:

1. www.example.com (main site)
2. www.example.com/site2
3. www.example.com/site3
4. www.example.com/site4

the .htaccess file of the main site, contains the following code:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.mynewsite.com
```

In this way, if the user visits the site www.example.com/site1, he is redirected to www.mynewsite.com/site1 which does not exist and therefore the page returns a 404 error. This applies to all pages and folders of the site to be closed.

Although it is not a good practice, I would like to redirect any page and folder of all websites to be closed, to the homepage of the new site, **except for the site www.example.com/site4** which must still be open to the public.

How is this accomplished? Do I have to work exclusively with the .htaccess file on the main site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect site with .htaccess but exclude one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this rule in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^site4 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mynewsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I created some redirects from the page of the old site to the corresponding page of the new site.  Where should I place them exactly?  Before the code you suggested?

Comment: Add new redirects after the `RewriteBase /` line and before the last rule that redirect everything else (except site4).

Comment: I realized now that the `RewriteBase /` line is commented. The line has never been uncommented. There is a suggestion but I don't know what it means: If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
 uncomment the following line.