# HTACCESS: Add FOLDER exceptions to RewriteEngine

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that evaluates any URL against their database and redirects accordingly to a php content or a default 404 page.

To develop a beta site, and add other folder for different purposes, I'd like to add these folders

- `example.com/beta`
- `example.com/products/`
- `example.com/photos`

as exceptions in the HTACCESS file. **Meaning, the site should read/render the content that is in these folders!** Instead of redirecting OR producing content based on the main index (`sample.com/index.php`). **Right now I can't access any files in `example.com/beta/`**

Used all the answers found in [StackOverflow: Exclude one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder/12144956) however, all the answers had the unfortunate effect of breaking the whole site instead of just adding exceptions **OR** sends me to the default 404 page (the "exception" folders ALREADY have index files, 404 should not happen)

Adding any of the following answers, just below the first `RewriteEngine on` didn't work:

```
...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteRule !^beta($|/) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
...
</IfModule>
```

OR

```
...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteRule ^(beta) - [L]
...
</IfModule>
```

OR

```
...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine   On    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
...
</IfModule>
```

At this point I am scratching my head as to what rule am I writing wrong to make the folder exceptions work. Below is the complete (original htaccess) file

### Original HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
    <FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Expires "Fri, 21 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT"
        Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine   On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteRule ^((.)?)$    index.php?p=home [L]

    RewriteCond $1 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ / [L]

    RewriteCond $1 !^(\#(.)*|\?(.)*|index\.php(.)*|content\/(.)*|css\/(.)*|picture_library\/(.)*|img\/(.)*|readme\.txt(.)*|favicon\.ico(.)*|robots\.txt(.)*|download\.php(.)*|admin\.php(.)*|\.htaccess\.back(.)*|\.htaccess(.)*|external\-export\.php(.)*|login\.php(.)*|cgi-bin\/(.)*|ioncube\/(.)*|test\/(.)*|sitemap\.xml(.)*|old\/(.)*|index\.php\?p\=404(.)*|C079CC0215D2E77B89B0F1837C8199B1\.txt(.)*|images\/(.)*|index\.html(.)*)
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
    RewriteEngine On     
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC] 
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 


    
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have htaacess rules file in following manner. I could see many issues in your current htaccess file, let me mention them and their fixes one by one here.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
    <FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Expires "Fri, 21 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT"
        Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On     
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
    
    ##This Rules needs to be more clear. 
    ##RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    ##RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$  index.php?p=home [QSA,L]

    ##This rule needs to be more clear too.
    RewriteRule ^httpdocs/?$ / [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

***Issues fixed:***

- First thing first we need not to use `RewriteEngine On` many times, just on time is enough in htaccess.
- Thumb rule never do domain redirection at bottom of rules, always place them at the top of htaccess file.
- Added `NE` flag to redirection which is required for sure.
- I observed you have used `RewriteCond $1` in few rules, well that's not possible in this manner, you need to give which attribute you are looking for to be checked.
- I have commented rule where it points to index.php if query string is NULL, well that is very much problematic since css/js/actual pages(uris) will come in this category and that will break your site.
- You need to handle above by applying it only non-existing pages(when you do that your existing pages which you are not able to access now should be accessed well IMHO). I have commented `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` rule I see we need to use index.php rules 2 times 1 with `?=home` QSA and 2nd one with normal one(`index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}`) if you could tell me difference between when should 1st rule get apply and when 2nd then I can edit 1st one accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi try this if it can solve your problem, here I am droping you my htaccess code if you found it useful please let me know.

1. 

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```