# 301 redirect of sub domain to main domain but root to a specific folder

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect my subdomain to main domain, except the root.

I did this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.main.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.main.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So this code redirects all URLs from sub to main, but I want the root of

> sub.main.com

to take place in a URL like this

> [www.main.com/sub-category](http://www.main.com/sub-category)

I tried many things. One was:

> First: sub.main.com to sub.main.com/index.php  After: sub.main.com/index.php to [www.main.com/sub-category](http://www.main.com/sub-category)

I also found something similar but i am stuck

[Redirect site with .htaccess but exclude one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder)

And many more ...

I couldn't get it done.

Could somebody please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.main.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.main.com/sub-category [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.main.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.main.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect:

1. `sub.main.com/xyz` to `https://www.main.com/xyz`
2. `sub.main.com/` to `https://www.main.com/sub-category`