# Apache redirect question - mod_rewrite or mod_alias

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have a specific need:

example.com/store/{location} must redirect to example.com/store2/{location}

And this needs to redirect, not just a url 'rewrite', so I'm guessing I need mod_alias, right? Anyone care to share the correct code for it? I'm a little fuzzy with both mod_rewrite and mod_alias. (I hope I asked this correctly) Thanks!!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808014/mod-rewrite-or-mod-alias

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to tell the browser to redirect its location, you simply can do this with [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect /store http://example.com/store2
```

Or the following if you mean it's a permanent redirect:

```
RedirectPermanent /store http://example.com/store2
```

As for your confusion, mod_alias is basically a simpler version of mod_rewrite. Quoting [GreyWyvern](http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/2007/09/12/apache-mod-rewrite):

> Essentially, if you're doing a "rewrite" which doesn't have any complex conditions attached to it, you should be using mod_alias. Conversely, if you want to redirect requests to files and query strings which you don't want displayed in the browser's address bar, you should be using mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/store/(.*)/$ store2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Strip the trailing `/` in case the user doesn't write it. And BTW @spadeworkers this is mod_rewrite

Comment: This didn't work. I had the following code in the .htaccess residing inside the store directory:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/store/(.*)/$ store2/$1 [R=301,L]

No errors or anything, it just simply didn't redirect.

Comment: And I did try removing the trailing slash too

Comment: I believe `RewriteRule ^/store(.*)$ http://example.com/store2$1 [R=301,L]` should work basically the same way as what I've suggested, and `301` can be replaced by `permanent` here as well.