# RewriteRule for 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I went through all the answered threads on rewrite rule problem. Tried the suggestions, But I still don't know what I am doing wrong.

I want to make a 301 redirect of our old URLs to the new ones. Example:

```
old url : http://www.xyz.com/abc/topics.html
new url : http://www.xyz.com/index.php#first
```

I am trying following rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\/abc\/(.+)$ http://www.xyz.com/index.php#first [L,R=301]
```

Any advice is highly appreciated

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^abc\/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/index.php#first [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution redirects to the destination page but in the url instead of '#' it displays '%23', thereby not scrolling to the anchor.

Comment: found the solution, Had to use [NE] flag as well. so now it is:      ^abc\/(.+)$ http://www.xyz.com/index.php#first [L,R=301,NE]

Comment: Details: `NE` flag prevents special characters (such as #,?,&) from being converted to their hex codes. `L` prevents further rules from being executed, which in-turn prevents possible "Invalid Request" warnings. See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 4):

You can, of course, do it by "mod_rewrite", but in this situation I'd suggest you use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) as it is faster and simpler (see this SO response: [mod_rewrite or mod_alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808014/mod-rewrite-or-mod-alias))

Like this:

```
Redirect permanent /abc http://www.xyz.com/index.php#first
```

Comment: I went through mod_alias, seems like it is faster. but one drawback is: xyz.com/abc/test redirects to http://www.xyz.com/index.php#first/test